# Trying to achieve a specific pattern for a background on illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, gradient, background, patterns

I am creating a logo for a charity organisation. I did find a particular logo that caught my eye. The following is the style I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I currently have a shape drawn out (the logo) however I am trying to achieve a similar background. How would I achieve this?

My first steps were to try and find the original background, but I could not do so. I therefore began to look for patterns and could not quite find a similar type. Even if I found a background/pattern, how would I achieve the same 'Red/Maroon' overlay look?

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not an expert in graphic designing, but any help would be greatly appreciated by myself and the community.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably benefit from learning how to create your own customised seamless patterns in Illustrator. There are lots of tutorials on the internet for this, but here's the basic idea:

This is a design which was created from a single triangle group, then reflected and rotated using 2 transform effects in the Appearance panel.

Then I made a copy of the graphic, Expanded the Appearance, and created a small tile from an exact square filled with a maroon colour, and coloured the graphic a greenish grey. I grouped both and made them into a pattern using Object > Pattern > Make.

Then you could easily create a rectangle above and apply a radial fill from black to white, and change the opacity to "multiply" in the appearance panel. Something like this perhaps

[image]

Here's a higher res view of the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3IF0.jpg